# How to initialize variable only if it is set up in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

How to initialize variable only if it is set up in controller???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the default value for the profile while defining the method and check if it is not the default value.

```
def initialize(profile = nil)
  if profile
    @profile = profile
    @person = profile.person
  end
end
```